# Trying to install a program and got an error asking a Python version that is already installed, and also a pip error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

As the title says, I am trying to install a program that has a couple of dependecies that demand a specific Python version (>= 3.7). I do not have admin rights, so I can't use sudo. The Python version installed is 2.7. Because of that, I used virtualenv to install and execute Python 3.9.5.

I executed venv, and checked the Python and pip versions:

```
which python
/home/honda/venv_python-3.9.5/bin/python

which pip
/home/honda/venv_python-3.9.5/bin/pip
```

I even checked the version using:

```
python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 10 2021, 13:50:25)
```

Which, as I understand, means that I have the correct Python/pip versions.

However, when I try to install the program, I get this:

```
./install.sh ../Programs/
Installing darwin binary...
Installing oma...
Installing libraries...
creating virtualenv for hog_bottom_up
Collecting numpy (from -r ../Programs//OMA/OMA.2.4.2/hog_bottom_up/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/1f/fe9459e39335e7d0e372b5e5dcd60f4381d3d1b42f0b9c8222102ff29ded/numpy-1.20.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-3_2_atp3/numpy/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.7 required.")
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3_2_atp3/numpy/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Cannot install python dependencies for hog-bottom-up inference algorithm
cannot create virtual environment for hog_bottom_up
```

To be honest, I don't know what is happening here. Is there something I am missing? I am not experienced in using virtualenv (I previously used another computer, one that I could use sudo, so I never had any problems like this, and I did install this same program there.)

Is there anything I can try? I guess could reach out to the admin and ask them to install the program for me, but I'd rather not do that yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you did the install command *inside the virtualenv you created*? Because from the logs it says "*creating virtualenv for hog_bottom_up*" which I think means it creates a new virtual environment. Check the contents of **install.sh**, because maybe it's using system Python, and not your Python 3.9.

Comment: Yes, I executed the install command inside the virtualenv. I cheched the install.sh and found no reference to using Python, but there were references calling other files that are executables, so I couldn't check them. However, I found a way to install the program using homebrew, and was successful with that. Thank you for the answer, though!